# SendGrid V3 api with C# not able to send mail from Console Application

Tags: console-application, sendgrid

I am not able to send email with SendGrid using the V3 API in a console application.  It works fine in my Web Application.  I created a test console project and used the sample code from the SendGrid site.  When the command to send the message is called, the application simply exits.  I cannot read any response from the call.

This is in VB.Net.  Sorry, I think I am the only person on Earth who codes in VB.

If I execute this code in the sample sendgrid-csharp-main from GitHub, it works fine.  I cannot find anything in the sample code that looks any different from my code in the section that actually calls the send message part (other than having to convert to VB).

Does anyone see ANYTHING wrong in this code?  I am using the .Net 4.7.2 framework.

This is the entirety of the test code.  I have been spinning my wheels searching for help for too long and I am desperate now.

```
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports SendGrid
Imports SendGrid.Helpers.Mail

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        TryIt().ConfigureAwait(True)
    End Sub

    Private Async Function TryIt() As Task

        Dim HttpClient As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
        Dim apiKey = "my private api key"
        Dim client = New SendGridClient(HttpClient, New SendGridClientOptions With {
            .ApiKey = apiKey,
            .HttpErrorAsException = True
        })
        Dim from = New EmailAddress("msie@msinvoiceExchange.com", "MSIE")
        Dim subject = "Hello World from the Twilio SendGrid CSharp Library Helper!"
        Dim toEmail = New EmailAddress("joe@invoicesanywhere.com", "Joe")
        Dim plainTextContent = "Hello, Email from the helper [SendSingleEmailAsync]!"
        Dim htmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email from the helper! [SendSingleEmailAsync]</strong>"

        Dim msg As New SendGridMessage With {
            .From = from,
            .Subject = subject,
            .PlainTextContent = plainTextContent,
            .HtmlContent = htmlContent
        }

        msg.AddTo(toEmail)

        Dim myResponse As Response

        myResponse = Await client.SendEmailAsync(msg)

        Console.WriteLine(msg.Serialize())
        Console.WriteLine(myResponse.StatusCode)
        Console.WriteLine(myResponse.Headers)
        Console.WriteLine(vbLf & vbLf & "Press <Enter> to continue.")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

It figures.  As soon as I get desperate enough to post a question, I figure out something that works.

I just hope that someone else has the same problem and finds this answer helpful.

This is the change I had to make to get this to work

```
    Sub Main()
        TryIt().Wait()
    End Sub
```